# Lime survey prevent users from voting for themselves

Tags: limesurvey

How do I prevent a participant in a long polling system from voting for themself in lime survey? Is there an attribute or plugin that can do this by tracking the email of the recipient and preventing their name from showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not be done sadly look under this link http://manual.limesurvey.org/Survey_settings , here is the full sentence under tokens headings Anonymized responses?: This allows you to determine whether responses to your survey are matched up with information from your surveys tokens table, or kept 'anonymous'. The default is 'No'. If you choose 'Yes' then your survey is set to radically anonymize responses - there is really no way to connect answers and participants.